# Custom Post Type - how to get video urls to automatically result in embedded video?

Tags: custom-post-types, oembed

I've created a custom post type that mostly follows the same setup as posts in order to more easily manage a particular group of content -- most of those posts will include multiple videos (loaded from Vimeo).

When I put a Vimeo video url in a regular post, the video is automatically embedded when the post is viewed. In my custom post type, the post just shows the url as a text element on the page.

What am I missing to make the video urls "convert" to embedded videos when entered on a custom post type? I *think* it's related to oEmbed, but I don't know enough to know what I need to do to make it work on these posts.

Thanks,
Scott